# TCL: pass an object as an argument of a procedure with ActiveTcl 8.6

Tags: object, tcl, procedure

I'm new to object-oriented programming in TCL. I installed ActiveTCL 8.6 which includes the package TclOO in order to use classes and objects in TCL. I would like to create an object and call various procedures in order to use it. For instance, I tried the following piece of code:

```
oo::class create Test {
   method func {} {
       puts "Hello World!"
   }
}

proc speak { myObj } {
   myObj func
}

Test create testObj

testObj func; # This prints "Hello World!"  

speak testObj; # This raises an error -> invalid command name "myObj"
```

What should I do in order to use the object testObj in the "speak" procedure?

Answer (score 4):

When you pass an object, you're *actually* passing the *name* of the object. The variable, the formal parameter, is then holding the name and you dereference the variable to use the object (and not the variable itself):

```
proc speak { myObj } {
    $myObj func
}
```

Note that you can also use a one-argument `set` to read the variable; this code below is equivalent to that above, but more long-winded:

```
proc speak { myObj } {
    [set myObj] func
}
```

---

It's also possible to make an alias to the object that can then have any name you want it to, but this is *not* recommended for procedures as such names are always effectively global.

```
# Don't do this!
proc speak { myObj } {
    interp alias {} $myObj {} myObj
    myObj func
}
```

This makes a lot more sense when you're passing an object into a constructor or storing it in a namespace that has many commands that may use it. (In fact, `rename` the object into the other object or namespace and the object will become managed by the lifetime of the entity which you moved it into; this is the simplest, most recommended way of doing UML Composition, and is used extensively inside the implementation of TDBC drivers. The key is the lifetime; procedure calls aren't usually things you want to limit passed-in objects' lifetime to.)